# Create a DataGrid in WPF with column type equal with DataGridViewButtonColumn of WinForm

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, wpfdatagrid

In WinForm i can programmatically add Rows on a DataGridView column(s) with loop, let say like this

```
private void rowsAdder()
{
    for(int u = 0; u<= 10; u++)
    {
         classSelect.Rows.Add("Number " + u);
         //classSelect is a name of a DataGridView, where the first column is a DataGridViewButtonColumn
    }
}
```

Then my questions are :

-What are the equal ways in WPF to add Rows in a DataGrid (using looped `Rows.Add()` etc) ?

-How to set the column type into ButtonColumn ?

If this help, i'm using .NET 4.5

Comment: @GrantWinney can you give me an example code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an extremely simple example :

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridUpdateSourceTriggerOneWay.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DataGridUpdateSourceTriggerOneWay"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid1" 
              IsReadOnly="False"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding data}">

        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Field">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="Auto"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Length of Field">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Length, Mode=TwoWay, 
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="Auto"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Here is your DataGrid, its ItemsSource bounded to data which exists in the codebehind below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Data> data { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        data = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        data.Add(new Data() { Name = "Data1", Length = 1 });
        data.Add(new Data() { Name = "Data2", Length = 2 });
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
 }
```

Collections need to inform their bound-view elements that their contents have changed (items added or removed ), that's the job of the `ObservableCollection<Data>`.

And here is the Data class:

```
public class Data : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _Name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }

    private int _Length;

    public int Length
    {
        get { return _Length; }
        set
        {
            _Length = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Length"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

The `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is part of an implementation of the Observer pattern for a specific purpose: to inform subscribers that the value of a property on the publisher has just changed. So, changing those two propeties, Name or Length on the instances existing the collection will result in a View update.

Let me know if you need more details about this.

Oh, i forgot, how would you add a new row ? Just handle a Click event for a Button placed somewhere on the View and add a new Data instance to data collection.

**Ex:**

```
data.Add(new Data() { Name = "Data3", Length = 3 });
```

Comment: It seems that i have some problems, `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ObservableCollection<>` won't show up, VS says it can't be found, am i miss something ?

Comment: Sorry, i don't know that i should include `System.ComponentModel` it's done now.

Comment: @TommyAriaPradana Ah, i've just arrived at work .. i am sorry i didn't give more details about it.. but i am glad to hear you got it right.

Comment: It's okay, your answer is really helpful for me but one more question, i've bound my DataGrid with a `ObservableCollection<>`, and i have initialize it but even after i add items to it, the items won't reflected in the DataGrid

Comment: @TommyAriaPradana You can run my example and see what's going on there. Add your collection as a property : public ObservableCollection<Data> data { get; set; } and initialize it just like I did. It should work. If not, post an update and we can work it out together.

Comment: so i've known why it won't be reflected, i forgot to fill `DataContext`, Thank you for all of your support, you save my day :D